# How can I configure nuget to not suggest Updates when Dependencies aren't met?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, nuget, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a number of projects inside a solution that are `.netcoreapp11` based.

In Visual Studio Ver 15.5.6, with Nuget Package Manager Ver 4.5.0,

I have a page full of updates that show Dependencies on `.NETStandard, Version=v2.0`.

Trying to update any of them results in

> Package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel... 2.0.1` is not compatible with `netcoreapp1.1`

I am not in a position to move our Solution to .Net Core 2 at this time.

How do I configure my solution or nuget to not suggest updates I am unable to apply?

Comment: Then, you can't use .NET Standard 2.0. That's only compatible with .NET Core 2.0. If you need to use a lesser version of .NET Core, then you need to stick with .NET Standard 1.6 or less.

Comment: [@Chris Pratt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654031/chris-pratt) - I don't want to use .NET Standard 2.0.  How do I confiugre that?  Its not in my csproj.  This is what I have there.
 <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>

Comment: Some library/NuGet your project is referencing has a dependency on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I configure my solution or nuget to not suggest updates I am unable to apply?

I am afraid there is no such direct configuration for your solution or nuget to not suggest updates for all packages automatically.

That is because nuget **only detect** if there is a higher version in all nuget sources based on the version in the `PackageReference` rather than detect that the version to be upgraded is compatible with the Target framework. Only when we install nuget package to the project, nuget will detect whether this package is compatible with the Target framework. This is default design for nuget. So we could not direct configuration for the solution or nuget to not suggest updates before we install that packages.

To resolve this issue, there is a workaround that we could manually constrain nuget package upgrade versions for each package by **specifying version range** `Version="[1.*, 2.0.0)"`:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="[1.*, 2.0.0)" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

In this case, when nuget will not suggest update that package to version 2.0:

[image]

Note: You should use a * is the correct way to float to a higher version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Everything that Leo said is correct.

In addition to that, NuGet has a plan to handle the scenarios of incompatible updates.

More details here:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5725